# SQL Server 2012 fails to use index when query uses hard-coded values

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I refactored a SQL Server stored procedure to use dynamic sql and sp_executesql.  I immediately noticed an enormous performance degradation--a procedure that used to return in less than a second now consumed upwards of 4 minutes.

After several hours of head-banging, I finally stumbled across the fact that when I ran the SQL statement with parameters it returned quickly, but when I ran it with hard-coded values it took forever.  For example, this query returns in less than a second:

```
DECLARE @Cat VARCHAR(10);
SET @Cat='Ginger';
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable a
WHERE a.MyColumn = @Cat
```

...while this query takes 4 minutes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable a
WHERE a.MyColumn = 'Ginger'
```

...and this query also takes 4 minutes:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = N' SELECT * FROM MyTable a WHERE a.MyColumn = @Cat';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Cat VARCHAR(10)', @Cat
```

(of course the actual query is more complex). I'm assuming that sp_executesql inserts the @Cat parameter as a hard-coded value into the query before it executes and thus reproduces the same problem as the non-parameterized query.

Looking at the difference in execution plans between the fast query and the slow queries, I noticed that the fast query uses an index that the slow queries do not use.  When I add a table hint to the slow queries to use that index, it fixes the problem, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable a WITH (INDEX(IX_MyIndex_3))
WHERE a.MyColumn = 'Ginger'
```

Adding the table hint to the dynamic sql query also fixes the problem there.

My question is twofold.  First: why?  Why would SQL Server treat a parameterized query differently from a query with hard-coded values?  And second, is there anything I can do to avoid the table hint?  For purely hygienic reasons I'd prefer to avoid peppering my stored procedure code with table hints.

I tried rebuilding statistics on the table used in the query, that had no effect.

This is not parameter-sniffing; while the problem surfaced inside a stored procedure I can reproduce it running queries manually in SSMS.  In any case, when I use a parameter in the query it works fine, it is when I switch from parameters to hard-code values that the problem occurs.

Comment: Is this happening inside a store procedure?. You should search for *parameter sniffing*

Comment: Yes, inside a stored procedure.  I don't think it is parameter sniffing; adding WITH(RECOMPILE) did not fix it.

Comment: That's not the only way that parameter sniffing can be prevented. For instance, if your sp receives a parameter called `@param`, you could use: `DECLARE @param2 SameDataTypeAsTheOriginal SET @param2 = @param ........(rest of the code here)`

Comment: I should have noted, this same odd behavior happens inside the stored procedure or when I run the statement in SSMS.  It is not parameter-sniffing.

Comment: And are the statistics in that table up to date?

Comment: Yes, I updated the statistics, it had no effect.

Comment: Well, doesn't really make much sense other than your query using (or re-using) an incorrect execution plan (which happens if the statistics aren't updated or parameter sniffing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127217/discussion-between-tom-regan-and-lamak).

Comment: It is normal that optimizer generates different plans for query with parameter vs. query with the literal value. Usually having an actual literal value in the query helps optimizer to generate a better plan. But, in your case it turned out to be opposite. Apparently, the query or data distribution is complex enough to confuse optimizer and generate a worse plan even when it has more information to work with. I don't see a simple solution. Analyze the execution plan and pay attention to areas where estimated rows differ from actual. This often gives a clue.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirBaranov, I'm afraid "confused optimizer" is the best answer I'm going to find, you can post that as the answer if you want.  Further evidence:  when I add and/or remove various columns from the WHERE clause the execution plan jumps back and forth between using/not using the index that I want it to use.  Since the SQL is dynamic I'm going to need to keep the table hint.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is structured like so:

```
DECLARE @Cat VARCHAR(10);
SET @Cat='Ginger';
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable a
WHERE a.MyColumn = @Cat
```

This is preventing parameter sniffing.  Under these conditions, SQL server develops plans based on guesstimated number of rows according to distribution of values in columns in the query.  These guesstimated plans are typically assuming some sort of even distribution of column values.

When you structure your query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable a WITH (INDEX(IX_MyIndex_3))
WHERE a.MyColumn = 'Ginger'
```

You are giving the optimizer more information, this can be a bad thing.  For instance if your column has 1000 rows with 10 unqiue values sql could assume each value occurs 100 times and decide a hash match is the best operator in a join.  When you give it 'ginger' and the statistics show that 'ginger' occurs 2 times it might decide to use a nested loop operator in a situation that doesn't make sense and cause a performance degradation. Or in the unknown scenario a filter operator might be used and in the known scenario a constant scan + nested loop may be used to limit rows. This is likely being caused by other problems in operators in the plan prior to the part where 'ginger' is considered.  As stated in comments above, supplying an exact value like this usually has a positive effect, but it can have a negative effect if sufficient information isn't provided in other parts of the query.